# Display a static page while building a Nuxt app

Tags: docker, vue.js, nuxt.js, bad-gateway, maintenance-mode

I am using nuxt js and I am wondering if it was possible, while the app is building, to display a static page, instead of having the bad gateway or the nuxt default building page?

My useCase is when I am deploying my app to production, I don't want the site to be completely down, but instead, to display a page that informs the user that the deploy is ongoing and that the site will be back soon.

I am using docker for my project:

- 1st container is a reverse proxy (traefik)
- 2nd is the front (Nuxt)
- 3rd is an API (Symfony)

When I build, http://localhost routes to my nuxt APP.
When building Nuxt, I have a "BAD GATEWAY" error (because the ap is building).

Do you have any idea?
Thank you all :)

I try to create another container that would handle the static content, but it does not work, as the nuxt container is shut down only a few microseconds while deploy. So the bad gateway comes back very soon.

My useCase is when I am deploying my app to production, I don't want the site to be completely down, but instead, to display a page that informs the user that the deploy is ongoing and that the site will be back soon.